# getopts not working when called with an argument

Tags: bash, getopts

This is my first attempt using getopts, and so far it hasn't been working for me. The code in my script is:

```
while getopts "s:" opt; do
 case $opt in
    s) subj=$OPTARG;;
    \?) echo "Incorrect usage";;
 esac
done

echo ""
echo $subj
```

When I try to run to script like this:

```
myScript.sh -s 100
```

I want it to echo the subject id number I've specified. So far though it just gives me a blank statement.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, outputs 100 for me. Are you sure you're running the correct script? `myScript.sh` requires the script to be executable and in a directory in your `PATH`, and the current working directory typically is *not* in the `PATH` for security reasons.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think my issue was also that I was doing source myScript.sh -s 100. When I just type myScript.sh -s 100 then it works. I'm not sure why it's an issue when I type "source"

Comment: Ah, I bet it works the *first* time you use `source myScript.sh -s 100` in a shell, though, doesn't it? The counter `getopts` uses to know which argument is next doesn't get reset between successive sources, so `getopts` simply doesn't see any arguments to parse. Explicitly setting `OPTIND=1` before you use `source` again should give you the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopts` uses the current value of `OPTIND` to know which argument to look at next. If you are using `source` to run your script, though, `OPTIND` never gets reset between calls. You probably added `subj` after the first run, so that its value wasn't set the first time you sourced the script. Explicitly setting `OPTIND=1` would fix it.

```
$ source myScript.sh -s 100

100
$ unset subj; source myScript.sh -s 100


$ OPTIND=1
$ source myScript.sh -s 100

100
```